# Working with Screen Space - Overlay canvases

Tags: unity, unity-ui

So, say you've started a new project. You drop your in desired sprite. You can see how big it is relative to the Main Camera. That's cool.

Now you want to add a persistent bit of UI to the game, so you use a canvas in the "Overlay" mode. That canvas is added in but is hundreds of times bigger than your Main Camera view.

My question is, are you all just cool with that? Or is there something I should do? It's a bit odd that there's some massive UI taking up so much space in my Scene view. If I want to add something to it, I have to zoom out for a while before it fits in my view.

I'm new to Unity development, so it's possible that's just how things are. But I was wondering if I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2):

It's like this because UI is usually laid out in pixel coordinates, rather than the game's world coordinate system.

I usually just double-click or hit F to center on what I need to look at, and use the Game window for verifying the look of the whole.

You can adjust your Canvas settings and PPU/reference PPU values to bring this layout space smaller, but in my experience that's been more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I think the "F" trick will actually help me out a bunch here. Glad to here it's something every dev has though, and not just something I'm messing up.

Comment: Yeah it's totally normal and something I don't like in Unity. You may also want to toggle of scene visibility of your UI (the little eyeball button that appears next to your objects name when you hover over it in the hierarchy) while you work on game play.